# Is a dbo.SORT table in a user database confined to only 1 data file?

Tags: sql-server, temporary-tables

A user thought he was exhausting tempdb because of this error:

> 'Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:  422291993526272' in database '<USER_DB>' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full.'

Since SQL did not mention tempdb, I inspected the user db and the default trace, and found there had been multiple autogrowths for 1 data file, until it reached its max.

Other data files in the PRIMARY filegroup apparently had plenty of space.

Could it be that SQL Server cannot extend a temporary sort table onto other data files in the same filegroup?

Comment: By "free space" do you mean free disk space on the volume(s) hosting the filegroup files, or are you looking at the Filegroups tab in the Database Properties? SQL Server uses a [proportional fill strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups#file-and-filegroup-fill-strategy) for the files in a filegroup. It sounds like you have a configuration issue if one file in a filegroup has completely filled - and expanded several times - while other files in the filegroup have free space.

Comment: By 'free space' I mean the free space inside the sql data file as determined by the FILEPROPERTY(...,SpaceUsed) command.  
The space used inside the files works as designed with proportional fill, but it looks like one particular file filled to its max_size with a sort table created by SQL Server. 
In that case an internal sort table would appear not to use proportional fill. 
Could that be the case?